# Detect mouse pressed events outside window Processing 2.0

Tags: mouseevent, processing

I am trying to find a way where I can click out side of the program's window and have the program pick up any time I press the mouse (Ex: Have Chrome or a game open and every time the mouse button is pressed processing is told the mouse is being pressed). I do not need any information to be sent to the program besides the fact that the mouse button has been pressed.

Thank you

Comment: [Some relevant code from the Processing wiki](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Mouse_events_outside_window)

Comment: "Processing to be running in the background (in other words, always stay in focus) while you are working on other applications" That is exactly what I want it to do. What languageS can  ran their pro grams in the background?